# isolate 'td a' tag based on class using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'd like to write the url links in this url into a file but there are 2 `'td a'` tags for each line on the table. I just want the one where a `class="pagelink"` `href="/search"` etc.

I tried the following code, hoping to pick up only the ones where `"class":"pagelink"`, but produced an error:

> AttributeError: 'Doctype' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Can anyone help please?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

writer.writerow(['URL', 'Reference', 'Description', 'Address'])

url = https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=city+of+edinburgh%2C+EDINBURGH&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&PAGE=0&DISPLAY_COUNT=1000&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=city+of+edinburgh&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&DD_TOWN=EDINBURGH&DD_STREET=BOSWALL+PARKWAY#results

response = session.get(url)                 #not used until after the iteration begins
html = soup(response.text, 'lxml')

for link in html:
    prop_link = link.find_all("td a", {"class":"pagelink"})

    writer.writerow([prop_link])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `html` variable contains a `Doctype` object which is not iterable. 
You'll need to use `find_all` or `select` in that object to find the nodes that you want.

Example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

outputfilename = 'Ed_Streets2.csv'

#inputfilename = 'Edinburgh.txt'

baseurl = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk'

outputfile = open(outputfilename, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
writer.writerow(['URL', 'Reference', 'Description', 'Address'])

session = requests.session()

url = "https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=city+of+edinburgh%2C+EDINBURGH&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&PAGE=0&DISPLAY_COUNT=100&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=city+of+edinburgh&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&DD_TOWN=EDINBURGH&DD_STREET=BOSWALL+PARKWAY#results"

response = session.get(url)              
html = soup(response.text, 'lxml')

prop_link = html.find_all("a", class_="pagelink button small")

for link in prop_link:
    prop_url = baseurl+(link["href"])
    print prop_url
    writer.writerow([prop_url, "", "", ""])
```

Comment: I continue to get the same result with this code. it prints each each href twice (as there or 2 href tags on each row). Could it be because the a class tag on the 2nd href is 'a class="pagelink button small" and its continuing to pick it up because of the word pagelink?

Comment: Thanks for the reply zroq

Comment: I'm sorry - my mistake. I've updated the code. Please notice the change `html.find_all("a", class_="pagelink button small")` -  It'll now give the correct output.

Comment: Got it, thank you, but with a small edit to anyone wishing to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. 
You need to look for the links before starting the loop.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

writer.writerow(['URL', 'Reference', 'Description', 'Address'])

url = "https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=city+of+edinburgh%2C+EDINBURGH&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&PAGE=0&DISPLAY_COUNT=1000&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=city+of+edinburgh&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&DD_TOWN=EDINBURGH&DD_STREET=BOSWALL+PARKWAY#results"

response = requests.get(url)                 #not used until after the iteration begins
html = soup(response.text, 'lxml')

prop_link = html.find_all("a", {"class":"pagelink button small"})

for link in prop_link:
    if(type(link) != type(None) and link.has_attr("href")):
        wr = link["href"]
        writer.writerow([wr])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I continue to get the same result with this code. It prints each each href twice (as there or 2 href tags on each row). Any others suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: @OdhranHennessy I have updated the code. It should work.